# Flask running port

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to run the flask application in a different port but it keeps running in 127.0.0.1:5000

At the beginning I am running these command in the terminal to initiate the server:

```
export FLASK_ENV=development
export FLASK_APP=app.py
python3 -m flask run
```

You can see it in the image:
[image: Terminal image]

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

Answer (score 1):

`flask run` replaces the `flask.run()` method so `port=5000` never get into server. I suggest you to run `python app.py` then it will use port you mentioned in the code.

However If you really want to do flask run via the terminal then I suggest you to set this environment variable `FLASK_RUN_PORT`

```
export FLASK_RUN_PORT=8000
```